# Alternative to .tar for directories with changing files

Tags: linux, compression, cloud, archive, tar

I'm attempting to back up a cloud server that has a service constantly running that updates specific directories with files. When trying to tarball the server root directory, it throws an error saying it some files changed during the process and I assume it stopped when that error occured.

Is there an alternative, more elegant way to archive and eventually compress a servers root directory if its dynamic and download it to the local machine?

Comment: You can instruct GNU tar to keep going even in this situation, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `--warning=no-file-changed` (and **not** `--ignore-failed-read`, regardless of what many blogs/online sources say).
Even with such option, I still get an exit code of non-zero and I am giving up at trying to understand `tar`.

I would like to know the answer to your question myself; I know there is [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/pax.html), but never fiddled with it.

Personally I advise you to use snapshots (if possible) and run tar on such snapshots.